# Create MySql query for search functions

Tags: php, mysql

I have some problem with query for search function in my site. I have a table which saving book data and in frontend page I have search function to find book by some search parameters.

This is my database table :

```
book_id | book_name       | book_location | book_qty | book_date
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1       | Triangle Math   | rack1         | 2        | 2017-06-12
2       | Basic Knowledge | rack2         | 3        | 2016-08-09
3       | Legend Truth    | rack3         | 1        | 2014-05-17
4       | Temporary Brain | rack4         | 1        | 2013-01-23
```

And this is my search in frontend page :

```
1. Input Field book name -- $name
2. Dropdown list book location -- $location
3. Search Button
```

The four parameters above is the variable to be use in query for get search result.

I already tried this query but not give me best result what I want.

```
SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE book_name like '%".$name."%' OR book_location = '".$location."'
```

When I choose just the location in dropdown list and leave field book name empty for example I choose **rack1** I got the result all the data is shown. I just want to get the data which have `book_location` in **rack1**. After I `var_dump()` the query I just realize that I got this query :

```
SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE book_name like '%%' OR book_location = 'rack1'
```

And I know with that query I will get all the data because `book_name like` is `'%%'`.

What I want to ask is how to make best query for search if not all parameters in search function not filled ? Thank you.

Comment: use if, if $name == ""; execute SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE book_name like '%%' OR book_location = 'rack1'

Comment: else{SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE book_name like '%".$name."%' OR book_location = '".$location."'}

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez If I used `book_name like '%%'` it will show all the data in the table.

Comment: I think you need a PHP ORM library, it will create the SQL query and return results for you and inserts the required params on demand if your are conditions met

Comment: @MpdelaVega What is PHP ORM library ? Do you have some reference ?

Comment: try this https://redbeanphp.com/index.php

Comment: Load a **whole ORM library** just because he wants to omit a part of the query if a string is empty? Benefits/drawbacks of an ORM obviously do not belong here but it looks like a lot of overkill for me. @Antonio, did you see my answer?

Comment: @Antonio did your question get resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `$name` is empty, then execute the appropriate query:

```
if ($name !== "") {
    // SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE book_name like '%".$name."%' OR book_location = '".$location."'
}
else {
    // SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE book_location = '".$location."'
}
```

You can also do it in one query if you use a short-circuit condition:

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE (".$name." != "" AND book_name LIKE '%".$name."%') OR book_location = '".$location."';
```

That will check the second operand only if the first one is also true (`$name` is not empty)

---

As a warning, you seem to be **vulnerable to SQL injections**. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)!